# SharePoint 2013 Maintenance - do I have to start/stop services?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Is a specific sequence in starting/stopping SharePoint 2013 Services? We need to restart our SharePoint Servers to apply important updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special guideline for reboot a server during the patching process. But, you have to perform certain things before start the patching process.You can do below things which will reduce the time as well.

- Gracefully shutdown the Distributed Cache. [Check this How to patch the Distributed Cache in SharePoint 2013](http://www.wictorwilen.se/how-to-patch-the-distributed-cache-in-sharepoint-2013)
- Stop Timer Service
- Stop User Profile Sync
- Stop Osearch Service [SharePoint farm where search component](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/03/13/how-to-install-update-packages-on-a-sharepoint-farm-where-search-component-and-high-availability-search-topologies-are-enabled/)

Now install the Binaries and if it ask for the reboot just do it. after that run the config wizard one by one.

Comment: Thank you Waqas. Do you have any document template that you can share? :)

Comment: there is no exact documentation but links i provide are good. Also i share how we applying the CU in our last many years. here is another good link for reference https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/04/29/sharepoint-2016-zero-downtime-patching-demystified/

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your setup.  In general, you don't need to worry too much about stopping individual services for a service restart.  The computer shutdown process will stop them and they will be re-started on startup.

Now - there is a special consideration with the distributed cache in a cluster.  You should do a graceful shutdown to ensure data is either moved to another node.  Google/Bing "Manage the Distributed Cache service in SharePoint Server 2013" to get the Technet article, and review the graceful shutdown procedures.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge Jesus Shelby.